# Record high quality videos

Tags: video-recording

I have used simple screen recorder and many other software's to capture the screen but the
saved video after recording is not of that great clarity with the default settings  . I want FHD videos .
What are the settings to record video with FHD quality ?

Comment: is your screen at least 1920x1080? Are you recording the entire screen or just a piece of it (one window, a selection, etc)

Comment: the problem is that you can't invent more pixels than are actually there. It is recording exactly the resolution that is inside the selected area, which is (obviously) less than the resolution of your entire screen. The only way out is to use some ML-type program to "infer" pixels where there aren't any, and upscale your recording. Or to play the video fullscreen on a 1080p monitor and record the entire screen, then you will get 1080p video.

Comment: You mean to say its not possible even if I capture the entire screen ?

Comment: if you capture the entire screen, and the screen has at least 1920x1080 pixels, you will get FHD video. If your screen has a lower resolution, or you only capture part of it, you will only get the resolution of the area you capture.

Comment: how to improve the quality of saved videos ? I want crystal clear video . I feel that the video is a bit blurred after recording .

Comment: Perhaps you want to increase the refresh rate to 60 FPS instead of 30? Is that what you're seeing as "blurry"? That option is in the regular settings.

Comment: 60 FPS improved the video quality  . I want to increase sharpness of video .

Comment: is it less sharp than what you're seeing when you record it? What encoding are you using? What frame rate is the original, and what frame rate are you recording at? Can you confirm that you're recording the entire screen, and that the screen is at least 1080p? Can you *show* what exactly is wrong (frame rate/resolution of the recorded video, for example. And settings from the screen recorder)

Comment: yes it is less sharp . approx 28 frame rate was original value for simplescreenrecorder . Which codec has better sharpness ?

Comment: @RajGopal Perhaps for your future screen recordings with SSR you could save as lossless and then transcode later? You will need a good CPU and lots of room for the output files; I use ffv1 and pcm_s16le for this purpose. Subsequent experimentation with H.264 or H.265 should then get that crystal clear screen recording you are after.

Answer (score 3):

Your video has been decoded - but you can't improve it. You are stuck to the resolution of the original video.
Any alteration of a video means decoding/encoding - which usually leads to very slight changes of the the copy.

Esther explains this point in one of her [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430230/record-high-quality-videos/1430235?noredirect=1#comment2491646_1430230)

It does not make any sense to "screen record" a video, except when you have DRM protected data - which is usually found on DVDs and bluerays.

**DRM protected data**

There are screen recorders that support ffmpeg.Or do it [yourself](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop). The advantage of using ffmpeg is that it can support the encoding of your GPU (e.g NVENC with Nvidia or VAAPI for Intel GPUs). This will get you the best results.

Comment: No, I thought you'd talk about "ripping. I'll revise my answer

Comment: Why is the open source community entertaining softwares like simplescreen recorder then ? Because there is a software I wanted to ask the settings for better quality of videos . This should make sense to you now . Its not about DRM or any other data .

Answer (score 0):

For sure, high quality screen recording is possible on Ubuntu. High resolution recording can be limited by the performance of the hardware. While UHD may not be obvious or supported by all screencasting tools, for sure recording full HD should not be a problem on the majority of hardware nowadays.

Read the manual of the application you use for the options to control the quality of the recorded video. Where it could go wrong is that the compression settings for encoding the video are too harsh, resulting in small files, however of lower quality. IF the default settings are not good for you, change them. You then, however, need to be using a tool that allows changing the video encoder settings.

Check the software OBS studio for professional quality screen recording. It offers plenty of control on the output format of the recorded video, both in terms of resolution - independent of your current screen resolution - as in terms of video compression settings.

This is a rather generic answer, but then, so is also your question.